# C++ : Nested Switch Case

Tags: c++

I have a for loop where when the quantity number is entered, the loop will run for the amount of quantity entered. But unfortunately the output summary only displays one output.

For example, when user enters the quantity number of 2, the loop of choosing the pizza, size and add on runs twice but the summary output in this particular line `cout << sizetype << "/t" << pizzatype << "/t" << price << endl;` only displays one output. Nevertheless, I want to display both of the output which has been entered by user.

Need help on this.

```html
case 2:
      
          cin >> quantity;
          for(int i=0; i<quantity; i++)
       cout << "**Pizza Favourites**" << endl;
       cout << "1. Italian Aloha" << endl;
       cout << "2. Vegi Lover" << endl;
       cout << "3. Ocean Delite" << endl << endl;
       cout << "Choose Your Pizza (Enter Integer 1-3 Only) : ";
       cin >> pizza;
       switch (pizza)
       {
       case 1:
        cout << "You've ordered Italian Aloha Pizza" << endl;
        pizzatype = "Italian Aloha Pizza";
        break;
       case 2:
        cout << "You've ordered Vegi Lover Pizza" << endl;
        pizzatype = "Vegi Lover Pizza";
        break;
       case 3:
        cout << "You've ordered Ocean Delite Pizza" << endl;
        pizzatype = "Ocean Delite Pizza";
        break;
       default:
        cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
        break;
       }

       cout << "**Pizza Sizes**" << endl;
       cout << "1. Regular (R)" << endl;
       cout << "2. Large (L)" << endl;
       cout << "3. X-Large (X)" << endl << endl;
       cout << "Choose Your Pizza Size (Enter Integer 1-3 Only) : ";
       cin >> size;
       switch (size)
       {
       case 1:
        cout << "You've Chose Regular Sized Pizza" << endl;
        sizetype = "Regular";
        price = newRegular;
        break;
       case 2:
        cout << "You've Chose Large Sized Pizza" << endl;
        sizetype = "Large";
        price = newLarge;
        break;
       case 3:
        cout << "You've Chose X-Large Sized Pizza" << endl;
        sizetype = "X-Large";
        price = newXlarge;
        break;
       default:
        cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
        break;
       }
}
       cout << "**Add On**" << endl;
       cout << "Do You Want To Add On Extra Cheese ? (Enter Y for Yes and N for No) : ";
       cin >> yesNo;
       switch (yesNo)
       {
       case 'Y':
        cout << "More Cheese, More Fun !" << endl;
        cheesePrice = newCheese;
        break;
       case 'N':
        cout << "No Extra Cheese Required !" << endl;
        cheesePrice;
        break;
       default:
        cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
        break;
       }

       cout << "WONDER PIZZA" << endl;
       cout << "************" << endl;
       cout << sizetype << "/t" << pizzatype << "/t" << price << endl;
       cout << "Extra Cheese : " << cheesePrice << endl;
       total = price + cheesePrice;
       cout << "Total Payment : " << total << endl;
       cout << "Please Insert Your Payment : " << payment << endl;
       change = payment - total;
       cout << "Change" << change << endl;
       break;
```

Comment: Create sub functions would help readability.

Comment: *Never* hardcode a password. There is no exception.

Comment: Don't just post your excercise sheet! Tell us what you don't understand and we might be able to help you but this is not a site for homework assistence.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can nest a `switch` statement inside the `case` of an outer `switch` statement.

The `break` on an inner `case` will be in the context of the inner `switch`.

(Does that answer your question?  I wasn't sure that was your question.)